# How to disable coupons from a certain category in opencart?

Tags: opencart, coupon

It may be a dumb question, but how can I disable coupons from a certain category in opencart 1.5.6?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a coupon from the admin panel, there is an option for coupon to add particular product and particular categories for that coupon.